# loop regex over a pandas series

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a list of words and I want to check if these exist in the column 'text' of a dataframe. I wrote the regex and I want to loop the regex over the column and extract the matching word, and then remove duplicates to obtain the unique matching words.

```
regex_list = []
for lex in deplex_fin:
    regex_list.append('/(^|\W)'+lex+'($|\W)/i')


matching_words_list = []
for regex in regex_list:
    matching_words_df = neg_sent['cleanText_emrm'].str.extract(regex)
    matching_words = list(matching_words_df.iloc[:,0])
    for item in matching_words:
        if str(item) != 'nan':
            matching_words_list.append(item)
```

But this is taking too long -- is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: 1) Create a trie from the word list you have. 2) Extract each word (use any approach you like, splitting with whitespace, regex matching with `\w+`, etc.), 3) check for each word found in the trie, 4) add to a set.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but  why even use regex here? What are you extracting? If you are matching the `lex`from a list anyway, why not simply check `for lex in deplex_fin`, `if lex in text:` ... ?